# Use yylex() to get the list of token types from an input string

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer, lexer

I have a CLI that was made using Bison and Flex which has grown large and complicated, and I'm trying to get the complete sequence of tokens (yytokentype or the corresponding yytranslate Bison symbol numbers) for a given input string to the parser.

Ideally, every time yyerror() is called I want to store the sequence of tokens that were identified during parse. I don't need to know the yylval's, states, actions, etc, just the token list resulting from the string input to the buffer.

If a straightforward way of doing this doesn't exist, then just a stand-alone way of going from string --> yytokentypes will work.

The below code just has debugging printouts, which I'll change to storing it in the place I want as soon as I figure out how to get the tokens.

```
// When an error condition is reached, yylex() to get the yytokentypes
void yyerror(const char *s)
{
    std::cerr<<"LEX\n";
    int tok; // yytokentype
    do
    {
        tok = yylex();
        std::cerr<<tok<<",";
    }while(tok);
    std::cerr<<"LEX\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code you already have? Also, try being more specific: what solutions have you tried already? Why did they not work? What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: Sure. First of all, I'm not trying to fix errors in the parser. Rather, I want to provide the client using the parser with some meta-information about the command that was just parsed, and the first step is simply knowing what the command gets tokenized as. I'll edit the question.

Comment: So what I've figured out is that the repeated calls to yylex() will continue to tokenize what's in the buffer at the point that yyerror was called. So I either need to reset the buffer to the beginning before entering this loop (although the contents may have been changed during parse), or I need to delete the buffer and create a fresh one, and then loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler solution is to just change the name of the lexer using the `YY_DECL` macro and then add a definition of `yylex` at the end:

```
%{
// ...
#include "parser.tab.h"
#define YY_DECL static int wrapped_lexer(void)
%}

%%
  /* rules */
%%
int yylex(void) {
  int token = wrapped_lexer();
  /* do something with the token */
  return token;
}
```

Having said that, unless the source code is read-once for some reason, it's probably faster on the whole to rescan the input only if an error is encountered rather than saving the token list in case an error is an encountered. Lexing is really pretty fast, and in many use cases, syntactically correct inputs are more common than erroneous ones.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured a way to do this without having to re-tokenize the input string. Flex allows you to define YY_DECL, which by default is found in the generated lexer file to produce the yylex() declaration:

```
#ifndef YY_DECL
  //some other stuff
#define YY_DECL int yylex (void)
#endif /* !YY_DECL */
```

And this goes in place

```
/** The main scanner function which does all the work.
 */
YY_DECL
{
    // Body of yylex() which returns the yytokentype
}
```

A tricky thing that I'm able to do is re-define yylex() via YY_DECL to capture every token before it gets returned to the caller. This allows me to store the yytokentype for every call without changing the parser's behavior one bit. Below I'm just printing it out here for testing:

```
#define YY_DECL                                 \
int yylex2(void);                               \
int yylex (void)                                \
{                                               \
    int ret;                                    \
    ret = yylex2();                             \
    std::cerr<<"yylex2 returns: "<<ret<<"\n";   \
    return ret;                                 \
}                                               \
```